# Custom page category taxonomy 404

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, 404-error

product/office/

return 404 error.How is that even possible? should it not go down to index if page is not found ?

This is my archive.php file:

```
<?php
  get_header();
?>
<div id="wrapper">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        get_header();
        if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
          echo '<a class="a-product" href="'.get_permalink().'">'; 
          echo '<div class="col col-s-1 col-m-4">';
          the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'class' => 'product-img' ));
          echo '<h2 class="h-product">';
            the_title();
          echo '</h2>';
          // echo substr(get_the_content(), 0, 100).'...';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</a>';
        endwhile; endif;
        ?>
    </div>
  </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my function.php What do I do wrong ?

```
<?php 

function create_product_taxonomies() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Products', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Product', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Products', 'textdomain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Products', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Products', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent product', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent product:', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Product', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Product', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Product', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Product Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Products with commas', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Products', 'textdomain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Products', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'No Products found.', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Products', 'textdomain' ),
  );

  $args = array(
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'public'            =>  true,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'has_archive'           =>  true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => false ),
  );

  register_taxonomy( 'product', ['product'], $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_product_taxonomies' );

function custom_product_post() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                => __( 'Products', 'text-domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => __( 'Product', 'text-domain' ),
    'add_new'             => _x( 'Add New Product', 'text-domain', 'text-domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Product', 'text-domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Product', 'text-domain' ),
    'new_item'            => __( 'New Product', 'text-domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Product', 'text-domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Products', 'text-domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'No Products found', 'text-domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Products found in Trash', 'text-domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Product:', 'text-domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Products', 'text-domain' ),
  );

  $args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'description'         => 'Wykonane zlecenia',
    'taxonomies'          => ['products'],
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-portfolio',
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'rewrite'             => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'supports'            => array(
      'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail',
      'excerpt','custom-fields', 'trackbacks', 'comments',
      'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats'
      )
  );

  register_post_type( 'product', $args );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_product_post');
```

Comment: You are trying to fetch the url `product/office/` but you register the slug `products` (with an s at the end) in the rewrite array. And don't forget to update your permalink structure as @Narek suggests. Hint: using the same slug for the cpt and the taxonomy won't work, although there are plugins, which should make that work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the [permalink structure](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) In the *Settings → Permalinks* panel